# SQL - Select Join and Group

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by, concatenation

The result of a SELECT statement by joining two tables is the following -

```
Col 1   |  Col 2    |  Col 3   |  Col 4
 ----------------------------------
sample11| sample12  | sample13 | sample14
sample11| sample12  | sample23 | sample24
sample11| sample12  | sample23 | sample34
sample11| sample12  | sample43 | sample44
```

How group and concatenate the values in col 4 for row2 and row 3 (based on the distinct values in col 3) such that the result is the following -

```
Col 1   |  Col 2    |  Col 3   |  Col 4
 ----------------------------------
sample11| sample12  | sample13 | sample14
sample11| sample12  | sample23 | sample24, sample34
sample11| sample12  | sample43 | sample44
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using oracle 11g

```
SELECT  "Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3", 
        LISTAGG("Col 4", ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "Col 1") AS "Col 4"
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY "Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3"
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/084b6/4)
- [LISTAGG()](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=515)